# UIViewController and dealloc

Tags: uiviewcontroller, dealloc

When new class of UIViewController is added in Xcode, template does not include a dealloc method.

Now it is not a big deal to add one, obviously, but i wonder if there is a reason it is not included in a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Apple wants you to use:

1. NIBs for UI components
2. Autorelease blocks
3. Automatic reference counting

All of the above techniques are taking care of the memory management process automatically. But it's just a suggested route. In Xcode 3.2 we had `-dealloc` in `UIViewController` template. And I use it often.